# Object tracking using image processing

Tags: image-processing

I am pursuing a master's in signal processing and I am working on object tracking. Till now I have done object tracking using colors, background subtraction and the Lucas-Kanade method along with a Kalman filter. For my final dissertation, I want to do something new on object tracking and I have explored a lot to get some new ideas but all in vain.  If anyone is working within the same field please suggest some ideas.

Comment: Particle filters.

Comment: This is really broad.  Choosing your dissertation topic is something highly personal that you should put a lot of time and effort into.  Ask a specific question about one of those ideas that you've explored "in vain", and someone can probably help direct your study.

Comment: Do something to improve this: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~saada/Publications/2006_SPIE_COCOA.pdf